# Segmentation fault when launching System Settings

Tags: system-settings

When I launch the System Settings application from the terminal, it shows this error.

```
(unity-control-center:3291): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue myself.

I was able to fix it by running this command: `setsid unity` and then restarting.

When Unity relaunched, it was working.

Comment: This worked for me (on ubuntu 16.04). Could you explain a bit on what is happening here and why it works? Thanks

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter 'setsid' on Linux runs the program in a new session so when you restart, essentially, you are starting a new version of Unity.